# TextArea Multi-Color text

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting

For my application, I am going to have syntax highlighting, in my text box. What I am not sure of, is how to do multi-color in one box instead of just one color.

I know I can do this, but it sets all of the text to one color.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ssccee;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author ryannaddy
 */
public class Sscce extends JFrame{

    JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();

    public Sscce(){

        setLayout(null);

        txt.setBounds(3, 3, 300, 200);
        add(txt);

        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
        txt.setFont(font);
        txt.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        txt.setText("\n \n JTextArea font & color change example");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Sscce jtxt = new Sscce();
        jtxt.setSize(313, 233);
        jtxt.setTitle("JTextArea font & color settings");
        jtxt.show();

    }
}
```

So, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A `JTextArea` is a plain text component.  It can display text in different fonts, but all of the text is in the same font.  You'll want to use something like [JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/).

> A very simple to use and extend JEditorKit that supports few languages. The main goal is to make it easy to have nice looking Java Swing Editors with support for Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: @RyanNaddy You might be able to get that to work, but I don't think it will be easy.  There's a demo application on [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#recap) that you can take a look at to see how text is styled in a JTextPane.